# iOS keyboard doesn't close, triggered by an input within an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, webkit

I have a modal window on my webpage which contains an `<iframe>` with page stored on remote server. This page includes form with some `<input>` elements. When user hits close button on modal then modal with iframe is hiding.

**Problem:**
If user starts typing something in `<input>` within `<iframe>` and then closes modal, keyboard doesn't closes until he'll press `Done` button.

I've simplified this example and removed modal entity and presented two buttons: one is hiding modal and another removes it from the DOM.

- [Demo](https://hostile-d.github.io/safari-iframe-issue/)
- [Source code
  if needed](https://github.com/hostile-d/safari-iframe-issue)

I've tried to play with `window.activeElement` setting focus explicitly to different elements on the root page.(you can check it on demo),  tried to call `.blur()` method on the `iframe` or `iframe.contentWindow`.
In my app `<iframe>` is hiding, but I've tried to remove it from the page.

Current behavour:

- User starts type something in `<input>` within `<iframe>`
- iOS keyboard opens
- removes/hides iframe
- iOS keyboard still opened even if the `<input>` doesn't exist or hidden.

[image: Issue screenshot]

I assume that keyboard should be hidden if no element it was trigged by is anymore presented, like it's done on Android/Chrome.

**I have few questions in this case:**

- can I resolve this behaviour somehow in my app?
- if it's a bug in iOS or WebKit is there some bug tracker provided by Apple or community to solve this kind of issues?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Responder Chain: UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("resignFirstResponder", to:nil, from:nil, forEvent:nil)

Using UIView’s endEditing:
self.view.endEditing(true)

Comment: It's not a native enviroment, just a website, I don't have access to this SDK.